# Odoo timeout killing cron

Tags: linux, ubuntu, timeout, odoo, odoo-12

I found in logs that timeout set to 120s is killing cronworkers. 
Firs issue I have noticed is that plugin which makes backups of db stuck in loop and makes zip after zip so in 1-2h disk is full. 
Second thing is scheduled action called Mass Mailing: Process queue in odoo. 
It should run every 60mins but it is gettin killed by timeout and run instantly after kill again

Where should I look for this timeout? I raised already all timeouts in odoo.conf to 500sec

Odoo v12 community, ubuntu 18, nginx

> 2019-12-02 06:43:04,711 4493 ERROR ? odoo.service.server: WorkerCron (4518) timeout after 120s
>   2019-12-02 06:43:04,720 4493 ERROR ? odoo.service.server: WorkerCron (4518) timeout after 120s

Comment: If you can modify these plugins, consider using odoo scheduled actions only for triggering other scripts for backing up/mailing. In that case Odoo cron job will be done immediately while actual job can be done later. For example, you can use some python queue manager like Celery of RQ. You just enqueue a task with Odoo cronjob and then it runs in other process.

Answer (score 4):

The following timeouts you can find in odoo.conf are usually the ones responsible for the behaviour you experience (in particular the second one).

- limit_time_cpu = 60
- limit_time_real = 120

Some more explanations on Odoo documentation : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/cmdline.html#multiprocessing